# Run-time error '1004' while entering a formula

Tags: excel, vba, macos, runtime-error

While running this on excel 2011 for mac, I get this error is:

> Run-time error '1004':
>   Microsoft Excel cannot find matching data to replace.  No cell in the selection contains what you typed, or no records match the criteria.

What is strange is that the program runs and the formula is entered correctly in the cells I'd like it to be.

The highlighted line of code when I click on debug is

```
ActiveSheet.Range("Q" & rowNum - 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=sum(R[-" & rowsToSum & "]C[-11]:RC[-11])/abs(sum(R[-" & cellsToSum & "]C[-13]:RC[-13]))/100"
```

Full for loop with error,

```
   For rowNum = 2 To lastRow + 1

          'checks if cells A through O in a given row are empty
          If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(Cells(rowNum, 1), Cells(rowNum, 15))) = 0 Then

            rowsToSum = 0

            'counts how many rows need to be added by checking if they are not blank.  Current rowNum will be blank, so check one above and count back up
            While Application.Sum(Range(Cells((rowNum - rowsToSum - 1), 1), Cells((rowNum - rowsToSum - 1), 15))) <> 0
                   rowsToSum = rowsToSum + 1
            Wend

            cellsToSum = 0

            'Counts how many cells need to be added by checking if G/L column.  Row above blank will have a value, rows above that need to be checked until non-blank is found
             While IsEmpty(Range("P" & rowNum - cellsToSum - 2))
                   cellsToSum = cellsToSum + 1
            Wend

                rowsToSum = rowsToSum - 1 'needs to be decremented since it counted to the blank row above the current transaction

                Range("Q" & rowNum - 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=sum(R[-" & rowsToSum & "]C[-11]:RC[-11])/abs(sum(R[-" & cellsToSum & "]C[-13]:RC[-13]))/100"
                Range("R" & rowNum - 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=sum(R[-" & rowsToSum & "]C[-6]:RC[-6])/abs(sum(R[-" & cellsToSum & "]C[-14]:RC[-14]))/100"
            End If
        Next rowNum
```

Do you know what is causing this error and how I can get rid of it?

Comment: upload full code including info about rowNum, rowsToSum, CellstoSum

Comment: When debugging and that line is highlighted, what is the value of `cellsToSum`?  Is it still 0?

Comment: Strangest thing, and I feel like this has happened a few times in my limited vba career, I retyped the line of code and it worked fine.  I checked it a few times to see if there was a difference but could find none.

Answer (score 1):

During the first loop of `For rowNum = 2 To lastRow + 1` the `Range("Q" & rowNum - 1)` cell reference will equal `Range("Q1")`. If the loop that increments `rowsToSum = rowsToSum + 1` increases *rowsTosum* at all (e.g. >0), then the use of *rowsTosum* within the formula at `sum(R[-" & rowsToSum & "]C[-11]:RC[-11])` would appear to be trying to sum a cell reference that is above row 1.